# How to drag and drop items to external container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui-sortable

Basically, I have the following markup:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.box').on('mousedown', function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        });
    });
</script>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="list">
        <li draggable ng-repeat="item in list">Item: {{item}}</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="boxes">
        Drop to external area: <br/><br/>
        <div class="box" style="background: red;"></div>
        <div class="box" style="background: yellow;"></div>
        <div class="box" style="background: orange;"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Fiddle**: http://plnkr.co/edit/xKw6sSbymA5M8R2v4OGF?p=preview

Now, I want to be able to drag and drop items from the list to that "external" container.

When user "drops" item to any of colored areas, I want to know that event just happend and which element is affected, as well

Already tried to listen for `mousedown/mouseup` events on each `.box` element, but it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: You need to trap the drop event on the target "external" container.

Comment: I raised a [feature request](https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/10628) for this 2 years back with no luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library you are using is sorting library. You need to use drag-drop library for this.

For example, you can use https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop

Refer the docs for all available event callbacks.

Copying the example code snippet directly (for reference check [here](https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop/blob/master/demo/dnd-filters.html)),

HTML:

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
    <li style='margin-left:10px;' ng-repeat="item in list1">
        <div class="btn" 
             data-drop="true" 
             ng-model='list1' 
             jqyoui-droppable="{index: {{$index}}}">

            <div class="btn btn-info" 
                 ng-show="item.title" 
                 data-drag="{{item.drag}}" 
                 data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid'}" 
                 ng-model="list1" 
                 jqyoui-draggable="{index: {{$index}},placeholder:true,animate:true}">
                {{item.title}}
            </div>

        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="container form-inline" style="text-align: center;">
    <div class="btn"
         ng-repeat="item in list2 | orderBy : 'title'" 
         data-drop="true" 
         ng-model='list2' 
         jqyoui-droppable="{index: {{$index}}, applyFilter: 'filterIt'}">

        <div class="btn btn-info" 
             data-drag="{{item.drag}}" 
             data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid'}" 
             ng-model="list2" 
             jqyoui-draggable="{index: {{$index}},animate:true, applyFilter: 'filterIt'}" 
             ng-hide="!item.title">
            {{item.title}}
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
App.controller('YourCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.filterIt = function() {
        return $filter('orderBy')($scope.list2, 'title');
    };
    $scope.list1 = [];
    $scope.list2 = [
        { 'title': 'Item 3', 'drag': true },
        { 'title': 'Item 2', 'drag': true },
        { 'title': 'Item 1', 'drag': true },
        { 'title': 'Item 4', 'drag': true }
    ];
    angular.forEach($scope.list2, function(val, key) {
        $scope.list1.push({});
    });
});
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you! The problem is that I need that sorting functionality, that's why it's used.

Comment: I see. Then probably you could check http://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/nested?

Answer (score 0):

Try replace the 'mousedown' with 'drop'.